# Multi threading in c synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying read the array limit and numbers and trying to find out the sum of half numbers using first thread and sum of other half of the array using thread 2 but thread 2 is running right after reading limit if array using thread 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

 void *method(void *);
 int a[10];

 int main(){
   int error;
   pthread_t id1,id2;
   pthread_attr_t attr1,attr2;
   pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
   error = pthread_create(&id1,&attr1,method,(int *)0);
   error = pthread_create(&id2,&attr2,method,(int *)1);
   //wait();
   error = pthread_join(id1,NULL);
   if(error!=0){
     printf("\n Error in Joining 1");
   }
   wait();
   error = pthread_join(id2,NULL);
   if(error!=0){
     printf("\n Error in Joining 2");
   }
   return 0;
 }

 void *method(void *args){
   int ch = (int *)args;
   int i,n,sum=0;
   if(ch==0) {
     printf("\nEnter the limit : ");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     printf("\nEnter the Numbers : ");
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
     for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
       sum+=a[i];
     }
     printf("\nThe sum of first n/2 elements : %d",sum);
   } else {
     sum = 0;
     for (i = (n/2)+1; i < n; i++) {
       sum+=a[i];
     }
     printf("\nThe sum of first n elements : %d",sum);   
   }    
 }
```

Output from compiling/running:

```
[leox@leox ~/nos_lab $ gcc multi.c -lpthread
multi.c: In function ‘method’:
multi.c:27:12: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   int ch = (int *)args;
        ^
leox@leox ~/nos_lab $ ./a.out
The sum of first n elements : 0
Enter the limit :
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0aNR.png)

Comment: Do you really want to be reading the array in both threads? Normally you would read the whole array in in the main thread and then use threads to process it. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: The computer is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: This statement `pthread_create(&id1,&attr1,method,(int *)0);` is trying to pass `0` casted as a `void *`. This is equivalent to passing `NULL`. What you probably want is to have `int ch1=0; pthread_create(&id1,&attr1,method,(void *)&ch1);`. The next line suffers the same problem. Change it to `int ch2=1; pthread_create(&id2,&attr2,method,(void *)&ch2);` and you should be fine. You can then define `void *method(int *args)` and in it `int ch=*args;`.

Comment: @TheDark i want thread1 to read the values to array and find the sum of half of the element and thread2 to calculate the sum of remaining. What  i want is to thread2 execute right after thread1 completes it's work

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now - there was an issue with the indenting, so it wasn't clear that `method` had two halves.I'll try to add an answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but might you need a mutex for synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want thread 2 to start until after thread 1 is finished, the simplest fix is to move the `pthread_create` for thread 2 to after the `pthread_join` for thread 1.

However, you still have a problem, because `n` and `sum` are local variables to `method` and the two threads will call `method` separately. You could move these variables out to be global as you have with `a`, or you could set up a structure to be passed as a pointer to the `method` thread function that contains the data you want to use/update.

Also note that making one thread wait until the other thread is completely finished removes any performance improvements you might gain from threading.